How could I convert this MongoDB aggregation pipeline updates to Spring Data MongoDB Kotlin/Java code?
Can I convert this aggregation pipeline updates into Spring Data MongoDB(Reactive) with type check?
I mean, it'd be the best if compile error occurs when the name of field in @Document class changes.
db.user_history.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userId: 23022569 },
    [
        { 
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: { 
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        { "userId": 23022569, "history": [], "autoIncrement": 0 },
                        "$$ROOT"
                    ] 
                }
            }
        },
        { 
            $set: {
                history: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $gt: [{ $size: "$history" }, 50] },
                        then: "$history",
                        else: { 
                            $concatArrays: [
                                "$history",
                                [{
                                    "_id": new ObjectId(),
                                    "sequence": { $add: ["$autoIncrement", 1] },
                                    "lastViewedAt": new Date(),
                                    "createdAt": new Date(),
                                }]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                autoIncrement: { $add: ["$autoIncrement", 1] }
            }
        }
    ],
    { 
        returnNewDocument: true,
        upsert: true
    }
);

Apparently there is no 'findOneAndUpdate' method in ReactiveMongoTemplate. What is the equivalent of it in Spring Data MongoDB?

Have you tried with findAndModify method (spring-boot 3.0.x+)? You must pass Query, UpdateDefinition, entity class and optionally collectionName.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/mongodb/template-crud-operations.html#mongo-template.aggregation-update  and thanks for accepting answers to your questions.
